# Asp.NET api with Odata [NotMapped] not working

Tags: asp.net, odata

I have restful api using ASP.NEt with Odata.

I tried to add a new property (that is not in database) to the model , when I run the server the result I get are correct but the property I added is not shown in JSON.

I tried to add everything like : [DataMember] [JsonProperty] and I have also [NotMapped].

I don't know why I get this problem. it used to work before.

```
 [Table("Etudiant")]
    public partial class Etudiant
    {

        public int StudentID { get; set; }

        [StringLength(128)]
        [IgnoreDataMember]
        public string UserID { get; set; }

        public int? Age { get; set; }

        [StringLength(15)]
        public string CodeName { get; set; }

//Problem is here.
        [NotMapped]
        public int? ForeignStudentCount { get; set; }


    }
```

and this is the controller :

```
 [EnableQuery]
        [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
        public Etudiant GetStudent([FromODataUri] int key)
        {
//put data in student ForeignCount property then return the result.
            return db.Student;
        }
```